# Unable to print output from class

Tags: python, class, oop, output

Could I please get some help. I've been trying out OOP on python 3.3. I have however encountered problems with printing my output. Here is an example:

```
class pet(object):
    number_of_legs = 0
    def sleep (self):
        print('Zzzzz')
    def count_legs(self):
        print ('I have %s legs' %(self.number_of_legs))

nemo = pet ()
nemo.number_of_legs = 4
nemo.count_legs
nemo.sleep
```

output:

```
bound method pet.count_legs of <__main__.pet object at 0x033D4230>
bound method pet.sleep of <__main__.pet object at 0x033D4230>
```

Any tips on overcoming this issue would be of a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually *call* the methods, using `()`, even if there are no arguments:

```
nemo.count_legs()
nemo.sleep()
```

A method is really just a callable attribute; you get the method object itself with `instance.attribute`, and call it using parentheses `instance.attribute()`.

Also, note that `number_of_legs`, as you currently have it, is a *class attribute*, shared by all instances. Assuming that different pets can have different numbers of legs, I would instead make it an *instance attribute*, which you can do at initialisation:

```
class Pet:

     def __init__(self, legs):
         self.legs = legs

     def sleep(self):
         print("Zzz")

     def count_legs(self):
         print("I have {0.legs} legs.".format(self))
```

(classes are named with uppercase by convention/[PEP-008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), unlike `%`, isn't deprecated). You can now make e.g.

```
nemo = Pet(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the `()`:

```
nemo = pet ()
nemo.number_of_legs = 4
nemo.count_legs()
nemo.sleep()
```

That way, you are actually making the method call instead of getting the method.

```
[OUTPUT]
I have 4 legs
Zzzzz
```